# Why doesn't xcode run the whole closure?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, closures

Why doesn't xcode run the whole closure, here is a screen shot:

[image]

It simply skipped all the breakpoints and went for that last one.

I thought maybe it skips those lines normally.

Then I couldn't find the value `x` (notice the first breakpoint) in the variables view.

And found nothing in the console (Notice `print` in the second breakpoint)

Then I checked my variables view, and I found that `self.news` has zero elements (Notice `append` in third breakpoint).

Then the app crashes.

I am stuck right now.

Please help and thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Know I know that xCode is really bad.

I changed my code to be like that:

```
self.news.insert(snapshot, at: 0)
self.newsTable.reloadData()
```

This doesn't cause the app to crash and does the work

Not the best performance though.

Thanks everyone :-)

Comment: With your breakpoint set to the third line, at reload row, try and do a `po` in the console and print value of `snapshot.value` and check if anything prints. Breakpoints behave erratically for me as well in Xcode 8 if i set them while debugging and sometimes in general, but the lines are always executed, they just don't stop at that line. :( Restarting Xcode or restarting the debugging usually solves it.

Comment: one note regarding lingo. it is not Xcode that runs the code, but the simulator and/or the device. Xcode is the IDE not the runtime.

Comment: that was helpful but isn't xcode that builds the app?